# How to use multiple conditions (queries) Cloud Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I need to use multiple conditions with Cloud Firestore as below

```
   child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: firestore
              .collection('home_posts')
              .where(
                'category',
                arrayContains: widget.categoryId,
              )
              .orderBy('date', descending: true)
              .where('exist', isEqualTo: true)
              .limit(documentLimit)
              .snapshots(),
```

How can I use where twice time with [category & exist] fields.
Is there any problem and my database structure bellow.
[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have here?  Is there an error?  If so, edit the question to show it, and be clear what your question is about your observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.where` methods should be chained together, and not in a different order, as per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#compound_queries).

Comment: So I can user multiple where if write as bellow      'child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: firestore
              .collection('home_posts')
              .where(
                'category',
                arrayContains: widget.categoryId,
              ).where('exist', isEqualTo: true)
              .orderBy('date', descending: true)
              .limit(documentLimit)
              .snapshots()',

Comment: @Abdalla According to the documentation, yes. Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If the answer solved your question, please mark it as correct, and consider up voting for relevance.